# How to customize and get the selected date from date picker when it is inside a static UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, uidatepicker

I have a `UITableView` and there are three static cells. For the third `UITableViewCell` `(indexPath.row == 2)`, I have used a seperate tableviewcell class, because I wanted to use a date picker inside that cell. So now what I want is:

- to customize the date picker(change the text color, text size). I have done small small things.
- next I want to disable the previous dates from the courrent date.
- fintally I want to get the user selected date.

This is my `UITableViewController` (static tableview)

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *cellIdentifier = [flightItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        NSString *defaultText = @"Please select a port";
        NSString *selectedText = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"st"];
        if (selectedText) {
            defaultText = selectedText;
        }
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = defaultText;
    }

    if (indexPath.row == 2) {
        DeparturedateTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        cell.departureDatepicker.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.4, 0.4);
        cell.departureDatepicker.frame = CGRectMake(0, 50, 200, 162);


    }
    //cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;


    UIToolbar *forblurEffect = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    cell.backgroundView = forblurEffect;

    return cell;
}
```

This is my `UITableViewCell` class (which I used for the third cell in the `UITableView`)

```
@interface DeparturedateTableViewCell : UITableViewCell 
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIDatePicker *departureDatepicker;

@end
```

Comment: datePicker.minimumDate=[NSDate date]; will hide all previous dates. datePicker.date will give you the selected date.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

In DeparturedateTableViewCell.m

```
departureDatepicker.minimumDate=[NSDate Date];

[departureDatepicker addTarget:self action:@selector(dateChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

- (void)dateChanged:(id)sender
{
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];


    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd  MMM  yy"];
    NSString *selecttime = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:departureDatepicker.date];
    NSLog(@"%@", selecttime);
}
```

Comment: in which method `departureDatepicker.minimumDate=[NSDate Daete]`

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to set IBOutLet for your DatePicker (as datePicker). 
Now code as:
NSDate *date =  self.departureDatepicker.date;

1. For disable the previous dates

   -(void)viewDidLoad {departureDatepicker
   .minimumDate=[NSDate date];

OR

```
[departureDatepicker setMinimumDate: [NSDate date]];

}
```

2. Get selected date

Put below lines in viewDidLoad

```
    [departureDatepicker addTarget:self action:@selector(startTimePickerChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

then add this method,
- (IBAction)startTimePickerChanged:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@“Date value is %@“, departureDatepicker.date);
}
```

Comment: I can't add this as a IBOutLet to the viewcontroller, becaue this is inside a static table view cell, that has three prototype cells.

Comment: Please create IBOutLet to the statictableViewCell.h file and then add this line of code in NSDate *date = self.departureDatepicker.date; in cellforRow method.

Comment: ` Outlets cannot be connected to repeating content.` it gives this error